# New Lines in Visual Studio C# output

Tags: c#, visual-studio, line-breaks

I'm working on some code which takes time sheet information and outputs it to a Word Document for employees to turn in at the end of each week. One section of the documents lists what week number it is and then underneath it should display the beginning and end dates of the week (i.e. 1/1/2015 - 1/7/2015); however, when I use the `Environment.NewLine` to create a line break, it instead adds spacing between the week number and week dates, rather than a return character for a new line. Thoughts or suggestions?

Here's the snippet that formats this section of the document:

```
{
    string result = string.Empty;
    result += WeekNo() + Environment.NewLine;  //the line break should happen here
    result += StartDate().ToShortDateString();
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it's your program and not Word that's causing the formatting quirk?

Comment: Your code is perfectly correct: it is then a word display issue.

Comment: I think, the "vertical tab" answer of this question helps:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24193619/inserting-a-line-break-not-a-paragraph-break-programatically-to-a-word-documen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My other answer was translated to a comment ...

```
{
    string result = string.Empty;
    result += WeekNo() + "\v";
    result += StartDate().ToShortDateString();
}
```

It came frome here:
[Inserting A Line Break (Not A Paragraph Break) Programatically To A Word Document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24193619/inserting-a-line-break-not-a-paragraph-break-programatically-to-a-word-documen)
If this other post is helpful please upvote the poster

Comment: Ah - I was unaware of the "vertical tab" character using \v - comes out perfectly formatted now! Cheers!