# C# Line Spacing in Word Interop

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

I am attempting to create a word document where the line spacing is set to "No Spacing", or single spacing.  I honestly don't know why this is so difficult.

I have tried all of these examples with no luck:

```
Paragraph para1 = document.Content.Paragraphs.Add(ref missing);
para1.LineSpacingRule = WdLineSpacing.wdLineSpaceExactly ;
para1.LineSpacing = 1;
para1.Format.SpaceBefore = 5;
para1.Format.SpaceAfter = 0;
para1.Range.Font.Name = "Times New Roman";
para1.Range.Font.Size = 12;
para1.Range.Text = "Mr. John Doe" + Environment.NewLine + "Address" + Environment.NewLine + "Anytown, AnyCity  12345";

Paragraph para1 = document.Content.Paragraphs.Add(ref missing);
para1.LineSpacingRule = WdLineSpacing.wdLineSpaceSingle ;
para1.Format.SpaceBefore = 5;
para1.Format.SpaceAfter = 0;
para1.Range.Font.Name = "Times New Roman";
para1.Range.Font.Size = 12;
para1.Range.Text = "Mr. John Doe" + Environment.NewLine + "Address" + Environment.NewLine + "Anytown, AnyCity  12345";

Paragraph para1 = document.Content.Paragraphs.Add(ref missing);
para1.LineSpacingRule = <tried them all> ;
para1.Format.SpaceBefore = 5;
para1.Format.SpaceAfter = 0;
para1.Range.Font.Name = "Times New Roman";
para1.Range.Font.Size = 12;
para1.Range.Text = "Mr. John Doe\rAddress\rAnytown, AnyCity  12345";

Paragraph para1 = document.Content.Paragraphs.Add(ref missing);
para1.LineSpacingRule = <tried them all> ;
para1.Format.SpaceBefore = 5;
para1.Format.SpaceAfter = 0;
para1.Range.Font.Name = "Times New Roman";
para1.Range.Font.Size = 12;
para1.Range.Text = "Mr. John Doe\rnAddress\rnAnytown, AnyCity  12345";
```

I am obviously missing something because every example turns out exactly the same.  There is extra spacing between each line of the address.

Anyone know how to make this work?

Comment: which library are you using?

Comment: Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word, runtime v2.0.50727

Comment: I might be barking up the wrong tree here because my Office.Interop skills are really poor, but doesn't a new line constitute a new paragraph? So by adding new lines to the paragraph text, when displayed in Word, it treats these as individual paragraphs and so the SpaceBefore and SpaceAfter takes effect?

Slap me if I'm wrong.
Update: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24193619/inserting-a-line-break-not-a-paragraph-break-programatically-to-a-word-documen

Comment: That may be so, but i have tried setting the "SpaceBefore" and "SpaceAfter" properties to zero.  Still no go.

Comment: YES!  Your link has the answer.  Using "\v" instead of "\r" or "\n" did the trick.  Thank you so much.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inserting A Line Break (Not A Paragraph Break) Programatically To A Word Document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24193619/inserting-a-line-break-not-a-paragraph-break-programatically-to-a-word-documen)

Comment: You guys are obviously better at searching for answers than I am.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Danel A. White to the rescue!

Using [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24193619/inserting-a-line-break-not-a-paragraph-break-programatically-to-a-word-documen), the answer is to use "vertical tabs".  I have never heard of them until now.

So, replacing "\r\n" with "\v" works perfectly.

```
    Paragraph para1 = document.Content.Paragraphs.Add(ref missing);
para1.Range.Font.Name = "Times New Roman";
para1.Range.Font.Size = 12;
para1.Range.Text = "Mr. John Doe\vAddress\vAnytown, AnyCity  12345";
```

Comment: "vertical tabs" in Word are called *Manual Linebreak* and can be inserted in a document by typing `Shift+Enter`.