# Java System.out.println only prints what's after VT character

Tags: java

I'm receiving data from a rabbit queue that I'm trying to convert to `String`. The message always starts with the SOH character and always ends with a VT character, followed by an ETX character. The data is received correctly and the byte array printed to the console is correct. The problem is that after converting to `String`, all the characters in the `System.out.println` before the VT and ETX are omitted. I first thought that the `byte[]` to `String` conversion might be done wrong by me, but I think there might be an issue with printing to the console that I'm missing.

Here's all the conversion approaches that I tried:

```
DeliverCallback deliverCallback = (consumerTag, delivery) -> {
            System.out.println("received message");
            String message1 = new String(delivery.getBody(), StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);
            String message2 = new String(delivery.getBody(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            String message3 = new String(delivery.getBody(), StandardCharsets.UTF_16);
            String message4 = new String(delivery.getBody(), StandardCharsets.UTF_16BE);
            String message5 = new String(delivery.getBody(), StandardCharsets.UTF_16LE);
            String message6 = new String(delivery.getBody(), StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);
            String message7 = new String(delivery.getBody());
            String message8 = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(delivery.getBody());
            String message9 = new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(delivery.getBody()), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(delivery.getBody()) + " - " + delivery.getBody().length);
            System.out.println("1 " + message1 + " - " + message1.length() + " - ");
            System.out.println("2 " + message2 + " - " + message2.length() + " - ");
            System.out.println("3 " + message3 + " - " + message3.length() + " - ");
            System.out.println("4 " + message4 + " - " + message4.length() + " - ");
            System.out.println("5 " + message5 + " - " + message5.length() + " - ");
            System.out.println("6 " + message6 + " - " + message6.length() + " - ");
            System.out.println("7 " + message7 + " - " + message7.length() + " - ");
            System.out.println("8 " + message8 + " - " + message8.length() + " - ");
            System.out.println("9 " + message9 + " - " + message9.length() + " - ");
        };
```

The `System.out.println` for messages 1, 2, 6, 7 print only VT, ETX and what is after, but nothing of what is before. The others are not properly converted and print asian characters or other random chars.

Comment: How do you know this statement `The data is received correctly and the byte array printed to the console is correct. ` is valid.  Did you debug the delivery.getBody() or?

Comment: It could be a `'\0'` terminating a string in C. Write all to a file, and check that.

Comment: @SMA yes, I took the byte array and decoded it using an online ASCII to text converter

Comment: @JoopEggen before the VT there is a carriage return character (ASCII character 13) could that be the issue, and does the `System.out.println` and does it reset the position to the  beginning of the line, hence why nothing is seen before it in the console?

Comment: I am not working intensively with System.out, but that might be the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Special characters

These are [control characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character)

- `SOH` is [start of header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Start-of-Header), ASCII code 1
- `VT` is [vertical tab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertical_Tab), ASCII code 11, escaped `"\v"`
- `ETX` is [end of text](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-Text_character), ASCII code 3, escaped `"\0x3"`

See also:

[What is a vertical tab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3380538/what-is-a-vertical-tab)

#### C0 and C1 control codes for message transmission

These control characters have not only special meaning (semantics) for printing but only for text transmission.

Maybe you need to put a special message-conversion component into place, when receiving data from a RabbitMQ text-message queue.

Comment: the issue was that before the VT there is a carriage return character (ASCII character 13). I removed it from the string and it now prints correctly