# Read multiple JSON files from storage in SQL and parse to table

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-synapse, azure-data-lake

I am attempting to read multiple JSON files using Synapse from a data lake storage container. I can successfully parse an example file pre-loaded in the SQL script, but I want to iterate through multiple files in the data lake (using OPENROWSET) and present the results in a table.

**So far, I have:**

```
SELECT 
    iotdata.did as Device, iotdata.dt as DeviceType, iotdata.c as PayloadComment, iotdata.mid as ManufactureId, iotdata.t as PayloadTimeStamp,
    ds.tp as DataType, ds.t as DataSetTimeStamp,
    de.*    
FROM 
    OPENROWSET(
        BULK 'https://xxxx.dfs.core.windows.net/raw/100/100/xxxx/2023/11/10/*.json',
        FORMAT = 'CSV',
        FIELDQUOTE = '0x0b',
        FIELDTERMINATOR ='0x0b',
        ROWTERMINATOR = '0x0b'
    )
    WITH (
    did nvarchar(100),
    dt nvarchar(100),
    c nvarchar(100),
    mid nvarchar(100),
    t nvarchar(100),
    ds nvarchar(max)
    ) as iotdata
cross apply openjson (iotdata.ds)
with
(
    tp nvarchar(100),
    t nvarchar(100),
    de nvarchar(max) as json
) as ds
cross apply openjson (ds.de)
with
(
    ch int '$.ch',
    m nvarchar(100)
)
as de
```

This produces error:

> Statement ID: {251445DC-2D85-4044-BF2F-34FE862FA8BA} | Query hash:
> 0x4C7DD120748CDBE7 | Distributed request ID:
> {F813A165-E978-442F-B61B-704D72E754E1}. Total size of data scanned is
> 2 megabytes, total size of data moved is 0 megabytes, total size of
> data written is 0 megabytes. Msg 13812, Level 16, State 3, Line 1 Bulk
> load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the
> specified codepage) for row 1, column 1 (did) in
> https://xxxx.dfs.core.windows.net/raw/100/100/R00016/2023/11/10/xxx-Received-20231110080054-MID-2xxx.json.

What am I doing wrong?

**Working SQL example, with a single JSON in embedded in the SQL**

```
declare @json2 nvarchar(max)
set @json2 = '
  {
  "did": "0001",
  "mid": "100",
  "dt": 100,
  "t": "2023-11-10T00:00:50.046Z",
  "c": "comment",
  "ds": [
    {
      "t": "2023-11-09T20:16:56.143Z",
      "tp": "100",
      "de": [
        {
          "ch": 100,
          "m": "2023-11-09T20:16:36.037Z"
        },
        {
          "ch": 101,
          "m": "2023-11-09T20:16:56.143Z"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "t": "2023-11-10T00:00:12.158Z",
      "tp": "101",
      "de": [
        {
          "ch": 120,
          "m": 13.189029
        },
        {
          "ch": 121,
          "m": 77.434937
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "t": "2023-11-10T00:00:07.054Z",
      "tp": "101",
      "de": [
        {
          "ch": 120,
          "m": 13.190003
        },
        {
          "ch": 121,
          "m": 77.44736
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "t": "2023-11-09T22:48:42.351Z",
      "tp": "100",
      "de": [
        {
          "ch": 100,
          "m": "2023-11-09T22:47:10.731Z"
        },
        {
          "ch": 101,
          "m": "2023-11-09T22:48:42.351Z"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "t": "2023-11-10T00:00:50.014Z",
      "tp": "103",
      "de": [
        {
          "ch": 145,
          "m": 35.935687
        },
        {
          "ch": 146,
          "m": -96.062258
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}';


select
    iotdata.did as Device, iotdata.dt as DeviceType, iotdata.c as PayloadComment, iotdata.mid as ManufactureId, iotdata.t as PayloadTimeStamp,
    ds.tp as DataType, ds.t as DataSetTimeStamp,
    de.*    
from   openjson (@json2)
with
(
    did nvarchar(100),
    dt nvarchar(100),
    c nvarchar(100),
    mid nvarchar(100),
    t nvarchar(100),
    ds nvarchar(max) as json
)
as iotdata
cross apply openjson (iotdata.ds)
with
(
    tp nvarchar(100),
    t nvarchar(100),
    de nvarchar(max) as json
) as ds
cross apply openjson (ds.de)
with
(
    ch int '$.ch',
    m nvarchar(100)
)
as de
```

**Desired table output**

```
╔════════╦════════════╦════════════════╦═══════════════╦══════════════════════════╦══════════╦══════════════════════════╦═════╦══════════════════════════╗
║ Device ║ DeviceType ║ PayloadComment ║ ManufactureId ║     PayloadTimeStamp     ║ DataType ║     DataSetTimeStamp     ║ ch  ║            m             ║
╠════════╬════════════╬════════════════╬═══════════════╬══════════════════════════╬══════════╬══════════════════════════╬═════╬══════════════════════════╣
║   0001 ║        100 ║ comment        ║           100 ║ 2023-11-10T00:00:50.046Z ║      100 ║ 2023-11-09T20:16:56.143Z ║ 100 ║ 2023-11-09T20:16:36.037Z ║
║   0001 ║        100 ║ comment        ║           100 ║ 2023-11-10T00:00:50.046Z ║      100 ║ 2023-11-09T20:16:56.143Z ║ 101 ║ 2023-11-09T20:16:56.143Z ║
║   0001 ║        100 ║ comment        ║           100 ║ 2023-11-10T00:00:50.046Z ║      101 ║ 2023-11-10T00:00:12.158Z ║ 120 ║ 13.189029                ║
║   0001 ║        100 ║ comment        ║           100 ║ 2023-11-10T00:00:50.046Z ║      101 ║ 2023-11-10T00:00:12.158Z ║ 121 ║ 77.434937                ║
║   0001 ║        100 ║ comment        ║           100 ║ 2023-11-10T00:00:50.046Z ║      101 ║ 2023-11-10T00:00:07.054Z ║ 120 ║ 13.190003                ║
║   0001 ║        100 ║ comment        ║           100 ║ 2023-11-10T00:00:50.046Z ║      101 ║ 2023-11-10T00:00:07.054Z ║ 121 ║ 77.44736                 ║
║   0001 ║        100 ║ comment        ║           100 ║ 2023-11-10T00:00:50.046Z ║      100 ║ 2023-11-09T22:48:42.351Z ║ 100 ║ 2023-11-09T22:47:10.731Z ║
║   0001 ║        100 ║ comment        ║           100 ║ 2023-11-10T00:00:50.046Z ║      100 ║ 2023-11-09T22:48:42.351Z ║ 101 ║ 2023-11-09T22:48:42.351Z ║
║   0001 ║        100 ║ comment        ║           100 ║ 2023-11-10T00:00:50.046Z ║      103 ║ 2023-11-10T00:00:50.014Z ║ 145 ║ 35.935687                ║
║   0001 ║        100 ║ comment        ║           100 ║ 2023-11-10T00:00:50.046Z ║      103 ║ 2023-11-10T00:00:50.014Z ║ 146 ║ -96.062258               ║
╚════════╩════════════╩════════════════╩═══════════════╩══════════════════════════╩══════════╩══════════════════════════╩═════╩══════════════════════════╝
```

A single example JSON file:

```
{
  "did": "0000",
  "mid": "100",
  "dt": 100,
  "t": "2023-11-09T12:00:54.055Z",
  "c": "",
  "ds": [
    {
      "t": "2023-11-09T12:00:07.508Z",
      "tp": "101",
      "de": [
        {
          "ch": 120,
          "m": 13.133502
        },
        {
          "ch": 121,
          "m": 77.360396
        },
        {
          "ch": 122,
          "m": "2023-11-09T12:00:07.508Z"
        },
        {
          "ch": 123,
          "m": 26677
        },
        {
          "ch": 124,
          "m": 5099.845
        },
        {
          "ch": 125,
          "m": 1
        },
        {
          "ch": 126,
          "m": "A"
        },
        {
          "ch": 127,
          "m": 0.02119
        },
        {
          "ch": 128,
          "m": 0
        },
        {
          "ch": 129,
          "m": 60273
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "t": "2023-11-09T12:00:54.018Z",
      "tp": "103",
      "de": [
        {
          "ch": 145,
          "m": 35.935687
        },
        {
          "ch": 146,
          "m": -96.062258
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "t": "2023-11-09T12:00:12.612Z",
      "tp": "101",
      "de": [
        {
          "ch": 120,
          "m": 13.133502
        },
        {
          "ch": 121,
          "m": 77.347973
        },
        {
          "ch": 122,
          "m": "2023-11-09T12:00:12.612Z"
        },
        {
          "ch": 123,
          "m": 2
        },
        {
          "ch": 124,
          "m": 0.0
        },
        {
          "ch": 125,
          "m": 1
        },
        {
          "ch": 126,
          "m": "A"
        },
        {
          "ch": 127,
          "m": 0.025042
        },
        {
          "ch": 128,
          "m": 1
        },
        {
          "ch": 129,
          "m": 0
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: What if you add a `COLLATE Latin1_General_100_BIN2_UTF8` in your `WITH`? For all of the columns from `did` to `ds `

Comment: I'm confused: is it JSON or CSV? If JSON why have you specified CSV in the `BULK` options?

Comment: @Charlieface 
Synapse serverless currently supports csv, parquet and delta (delta lake). OPENROWSET does not support json as a separate format. As json and csv are both similar text files, csv-format with suitable parameters is used for reading json.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70803261/azure-synapse-query-json-using-openrowset-fieldterminator-value-0x0b#:~:text=OPENROWSET%20is%20created%20for%20reading,is%20used%20for%20reading%20json.

Comment: @MartinSmith same error when I add COLLATE Latin1_General_100_BIN2_UTF8

Comment: I've not used Synapse, but I see that is documented here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/query-json-files It says you should use ` with (doc nvarchar(max)) as rows` after the `openrowset`, and therefore you need another `openjson` to shred the first level. I must say it feels strange to specify `0x0b` as the row or field terminator as you can have embedded newlines. Probably better to specify some character which does not appear anywhere, so as to get it as one big blob.

Comment: @Charlieface - `0x0b` is vertical tab

Comment: yep, that character doesn't appear in the JSON which I think is why it's used in the MS examples I suspect.

Comment: just a guess but can it be that different files have different schemas

Comment: In this context use of `0x0b` is a dirty hack. According to the JSON spec it's not a legal character to use (only `0x09`, `0x0A`, `0x0D` and `0x20` in the whitespace range are permissible), so the author of the Microsoft examples has apparently set the quote, field terminator and row terminator characters to that in an effort to read in the JSON data with fake `single_clob` handling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When Json object is stored in the variable `json2`, you used `openjson` to parse the Json variable `json2`.  If you want to read and parse the Json file, you need to use `JSONVALUE` for parsing the Json value that are read with `openrowset` . Below is the modified code.

**Code:**

```sql
SELECT
JSON_VALUE(ds,'$.did') as deviceid,JSON_VALUE(ds, '$.dt') as DeviceType, JSON_VALUE(ds,'$.c') as PayloadComment,
JSON_VALUE(ds,'$.mid') as ManufactureId, JSON_VALUE(ds,'$.t') as PayloadTimeStamp,
ds1.tp as [DataType], ds1.t as DataSetTimeStamp
,ch,m
FROM
OPENROWSET(
BULK  'https://xxx.blob.core.windows.net/xxx/xx/xxx.json',
FORMAT = 'CSV',
FIELDQUOTE = '0x0b',
FIELDTERMINATOR ='0x0b',
ROWTERMINATOR = '0x0b'
)
WITH (
ds nvarchar(max)
) as iotdata
cross  apply openjson (ds,'$.ds')
with
(
tp nvarchar(100) '$.tp',
t nvarchar(100) '$.t',
de nvarchar(max) as json
) as ds1
cross  apply openjson (de)
with
(
ch int  '$.ch',
m nvarchar(100) '$.m'
) as de
```

**Output:**

Output data for the above code with sample Json file ,

| deviceid | DeviceType | PayloadComment | ManufactureId | PayloadTimeStamp | DataType | DataSetTimeStamp | ch | m |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0001 | 100 | comment | 100 | 2023-11-10T00:00:50.046Z | 100 | 2023-11-09T20:16:56.143Z | 100 | 2023-11-09T20:16:36.037Z |
| 0001 | 100 | comment | 100 | 2023-11-10T00:00:50.046Z | 100 | 2023-11-09T20:16:56.143Z | 101 | 2023-11-09T20:16:56.143Z |
| 0001 | 100 | comment | 100 | 2023-11-10T00:00:50.046Z | 101 | 2023-11-10T00:00:12.158Z | 120 | 13.189029 |
| 0001 | 100 | comment | 100 | 2023-11-10T00:00:50.046Z | 101 | 2023-11-10T00:00:12.158Z | 121 | 77.434937 |
| 0001 | 100 | comment | 100 | 2023-11-10T00:00:50.046Z | 101 | 2023-11-10T00:00:07.054Z | 120 | 13.190003 |
| 0001 | 100 | comment | 100 | 2023-11-10T00:00:50.046Z | 101 | 2023-11-10T00:00:07.054Z | 121 | 77.44736 |
| 0001 | 100 | comment | 100 | 2023-11-10T00:00:50.046Z | 100 | 2023-11-09T22:48:42.351Z | 100 | 2023-11-09T22:47:10.731Z |
| 0001 | 100 | comment | 100 | 2023-11-10T00:00:50.046Z | 100 | 2023-11-09T22:48:42.351Z | 101 | 2023-11-09T22:48:42.351Z |
| 0001 | 100 | comment | 100 | 2023-11-10T00:00:50.046Z | 103 | 2023-11-10T00:00:50.014Z | 145 | 35.935687 |
| 0001 | 100 | comment | 100 | 2023-11-10T00:00:50.046Z | 103 | 2023-11-10T00:00:50.014Z | 146 | -96.062258 |

[image]

Comment: Thank you (again). I am trying to get my head around this I promise.