# How to replace Line Tabulation (\\u000B or ) in String using Java?

Tags: java, string, replace, unicode, replaceall

- The Data looks somewhat like following in database: ()

[image]

- When record is fetched from database and rest service responded it looks like :

  ```
  ICT0637256 Onboarding questionnaire for internal transfers & dashboard\u000BOnboarding
  ```
- Another wrapper service which returns soap response; when call this rest service, then it returns following response :

  ```
  <ns7:TaskDescription>ICT0637256 Onboarding questionnaire for internal transfers &amp; dashboard&#11;Onboarding</ns7:TaskDescription>
  ```

I searched on internet and found \u000B is line tabulation.

Now on soap service level, i am trying to replace character comes from Rest Service:

```
  public String replaceUnnecessaryCharacters(String text) {
        if(StringUtils.isNotEmpty(text)) {
            text = text.replaceAll("\\\\u000B", " ");
            text = text.replaceAll("&#11;", " ");
            text = text.replaceAll("<0x0b>", " ");
            text = text.replaceAll("\\^K", " ");
        }
        return text;
    }

    if(task.getProjectId() == 5130764) {
        LOG.info("getTasks: DescriptionDetails:5130764" + task.getDescription()); //<-- This comes from Rest API in code
        LOG.info("getTasks: DescriptionDetails:5130764" + replaceUnnecessaryCharacters(task.getDescription())); <--- Here it doesn't show \u00B but blank space
    }soapResponsetsk.setTaskDescription(replaceUnnecessaryCharacters(task.getDescription()));
```

- When i copy it in notepad, it looks like

[image]

- When i copy it to VI Editor in linux then it shows ^K

I am like lost how to replace this character using Java? Can you please suggest how to fix the same?

Comment: Add it to answer. Pshemo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are not really using any of regex syntax (like `+` `*` quantifiers, `\w` character classes, etc.) instead of `replaceAll` you can use `replace` method.

Also since you want to replace single character with another character you can use [`replace(char oldChar, char newChar)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#replace(char,char)) like

```
text = text.replace('\u000B', ' ');
```

Comment: Thanks. How can i write this character using keyboard? can you give an idea. It is not space or tab but something else?

Comment: I never needed to write it so I honestly don't know. Edit: Based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/3385152 it looks like it is `Ctrl` + `Enter` in Microsoft Word documents.

Comment: But when you decide to use the regex engine, you can use `text = text.replaceAll("\\v", " ");`